# Journey entry Data Extension created from Salesforce Data has blank column length

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I am trying to configure a Journey in SFMC using Salesforce data as an entry source. The data extension that is getting created with Salesforce fields has all the column length as blank.
As a result when I am trying to use the LookupOrderedRows function in emails and validating I am getting the error:

> "The Data Extension Key field for a LookupOrderedRows function call is
>   invalid. The key field has a MAX or unlimited length. Fields with MAX
>   or unlimited length cannot be used as keys".

SFMC is also not allowing me to edit the field lengths in the data extension thus created.

Comment: can you please post a copy of your code?

Comment: set @couponRows = LookupOrderedRows("DE NAME",1,"COLUMN1 desc","COLUMN2","123","COLUMN3","false")

The column2 has no length in the data extension (created from Sales force Data used in the journey entry source)

Comment: @androemedaandroemeda still need more info